# Multiselect listbox with search option

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, sql-server

I was working in asp.net C#,  I am trying to do multi-select list box with search option in the same tool but search option is not including please help.

thanks in advance

Comment: Add plugins like this by using jquery: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Searchable-Multi-select-jQuery-Dropdown/

Comment: Show your code to help us determine your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with razor? If you are, it automatically permit you to start writing in the list and it select the item which starts with the char you entered

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JQuery plugin called chosen (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). Download the plugin and copy the chosen files to your app. You can pass your items through the view model in your razor page and populate it like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select data-placeholder="choose items" class="search-select form-control" required
     asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Items, "Id", "Name")" multiple>
    </select>
</div>
```

Finally, when you load your view activate the plugin by calling `$(".search-select").chosen()`